# Mac OS: 7.5.3 Command-Turn On

Tags: classic-mac-os

I'm not a mac user anymore. But I used to be one when I was a kid.
My father had a Macintosh Performa 6200 running MacOS 7.5.3.

On said MacOS you could press command + the turn on key on the keyboard, and a white rectangle with a textcursor would appear.

Does anyone know what type of commands (and in what language) this box expected?

I googled around and found no mention of this textbox. Until this day I have not the slightest idea what that thing was.

Comment: That does ring a bell but vaguely... I **believe** that dropped you into the NVRAM firmware allowing you to set boot arguments and other things stored in nvram/pram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that was MacsBug! (IIRC it was a System Extension that had to be installed/enabled -- although it's been quite a number of years...)

I found a command reference for it here:
[MacsBug Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20110605022118/http://developer.apple.com/tools/debuggers/MacsBug/Documentation/MacsBugRef_6.2.pdf).

There's some more info over on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacsBug).

Comment: Small correction: It was not an (optional) extension. I can safely say that my dad would never install any debug extensions.

Comment: You can see in the reference manual, and on wikipedia that it was indeed optional.

Comment: MacsBug was the big, fancy assembly-language debugger.  Without it installed, you got the ROM debugger instead, which had far more limited capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

That was the Debugger window that was built into the Mac's ROM. I never learned what language worked in it.